# GPU is plugged in, but isn't registered by PC. Why is that?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

My monitor is plugged into the the gpu, so it clearly isn't dead, however BIOS can't see it, device manager won't see it (no matter how many CMD commands I try). Not even getting GeForce Experience or NVIDIA drivers worked, and I have tried about every question and answer on the internet there is on this topic. I considered that the motherboard might not support the gpu, but that's stupid and I wouldn't get a feed to my monitor. First build too, great start so far aha.

PC specs:

- [AMD A8-6600k](http://products.amd.com/en-ca/search/APU/AMD-A-Series-Processors/AMD-A8-Series-APU-for-Desktops/A8-6600K-with-Radeon%E2%84%A2-HD-8570D/61)
- [NVIDIA GTX 650](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650)
- [Gigabyte GA-F2A52M-HD2](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-F2A68HM-HD2-rev-11#ov)
- EVGA 550W G2 GOLD
- Windows 10

If you need any more specs, then just ask, I thought these would be the important ones.

Comment: I wonder if the PCIe port's supplying enough power. It *should*. Also, could you get a friend to test the video card on his system, or a known good video card on yours?

Comment: Hm... so you're saying it doesn't appear under the `Display Adapters` node in Device Manager? Does anything else appear there?

Comment: Nope, but the graphics with my cpu do though. Even if I click ‘view hidden devices’. I tried looking in ports but the PCI port doesn't seem to register the gpu.

Comment: Did you connect the 6 pin power connector to your graphics card?

Comment: Yeah, both, but that couldn't cause it to be ‘invisible’, surely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU was appearing as an AMD GPU, and my integrated graphics were disabled. As a result I couldn't update the AMD or NVIDIA drivers since the graphics card isn't an AMD GPU nor was it being detected as an NVIDIA one either.

Uninstalling everything made Windows reset it to a basic adapter which then allowed me to install the right driver.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if the supported technologies PCIe/PCIe2/PCIe3 etc.. required by your graphics card is set in the BIOS. Setting PCIe3 would help your card.

Since yours is a Nvidia card and that motherboard (Gigabyte GA-F2A52M-HD2) is more tuned to sport dual Radeons, try disabling AMD specific graphics features.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you connected your monitor to a real graphic card and not to an integrated one? The real could still be dead and you are just plugged to  integrated GPU.

Comment: It is definitely plugged into the GPU, because the ports related to the motherboard are at the top rear of the case and my HDMI cable is plugged in at the bottom. Although now you say this, when I plug my cable into the motherboard, no video is shown, but that is the only graphics my computer detects. Weird.